# Same path works fine with files and does not with folder

Tags: c#, path, directory

```
 private void bt_edit_folder_name_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Directory.Move("\\\\192.168.1.244\old_name", "\\\\192.168.1.244\new_name");
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
```

I've used the same path to change the FILE name and it works fine BUT I can not use the same path to change the folder name.
it show this debug error:

> ```
> The specified path is invalid
> ```

Comment: Written like that, your strings would contain a newline and the nonexistent escape character `\o` - what is your actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you  can use [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to solve your issue

```
 Directory.Move(@"\\192.168.1.244\old_name", @"\\192.168.1.244\new_name");
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works fine now with both files and folders (directories), I've spent many hours trying to solve this issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

if you have trouble to move directories using c#, then you can try to do with cmd commands using process it should work,

```
    String command="xcopy "+srcPath+" "+destPath+" /i /q /s /y";
    Process p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()  {
        FileName = "cmd",
        Arguments = "/c \"" + command + "\"",
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    });
    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();//read error & feedback messages
    string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could be getting this exception is if you don't meet the naming conventions. [The documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> sourceDirName or destDirName is a zero-length string, contains only white space, or contains one or more invalid characters as defined by [InvalidPathChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.invalidpathchars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So, in other words, the `destDirName` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\192.168.1.244\old_name");
dir.MoveTo(@"\\192.168.1.244\tmpName");
dir.MoveTo(@"\\192.168.1.244\new_name");
```